# no R.attr.textPrimaryColor in AppCompat v7 r21

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

In the documentation for SDK 21 there's an R.attr.textPrimaryColor attribute that supposedly sets the toolbar's title color according to this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

That attribute, however, does not exist in the AppCompat theme included in the AppCompat v7 r21 support library. How exactly can we set the title's color through a theme rather than through code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
/>

<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?actionBarIconColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, since it will also override the color of the subtitle and themed icons (e.g. overflow).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to override *only* the color of the toolbar title, you can override the toolbar's title text appearance. This will not, however, affect the color of any themed icons (e.g. overflow icon) or the color of the subtitle. For those you would want to specify a theme overlay as in the other answer.

res/layout/my_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/MyToolbarStyle" />
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyToolbarTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTextAppearance"
       parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```